# How to add texture to my model?

Tags: texturing

I'm new to blender. I have a version 2.90 and I  wanna apply the texture to my building model. But I can't do it is there anyone how to create a texture or import it from anywhere and then apply?

I know it's a dumb question but don't mind. Everyone should help each other!

Comment: I recommend you to check the Blender fundamentals over the Blender channel to learn about shading and textures because is better for you to see the actual process. https://youtu.be/RRilLLyyn1Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an image texture can be as simple as going to the Material Properties tab (the little globe near the bottom - covered in this image), and selecting a new material (hit the plus button if there is no material already there). From here you can click on the input of the BaseColor, and choose Image texture. A box will appear allowing you to choose an image file from your PC.

[image: Textures]

If you need free textures, one good place to get them is https://3dtextures.me/

However, this site provides full PBR texture sets, which though look the best, are a bit more complicated to set up. this process can be made much easier by the help of a free addon. Go to user preferences, add-ons, and search for "node wrangler". Enable it.

[image: Wrangler]

From here, if you go to your shading tab, you can select the Principled BSDF and add whole PBR texture sets at once by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, or a single image by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: Wrangler2]

Remember that your object must be UV unwrapped for materials to apply correctly. it works on the default cube because it comes with a pre-generated UV map.

Comment: Ok thanks for you help buddy!

Comment: No problem. As Emir pointed out in his comment, texturing and materials can be a rather complicated subject, and therefore it is probably best to familiarize yourself with the process as much as possible. Here's a link to a (rather thorough - read: long) guide. - https://artisticrender.com/how-to-add-a-texture-to-an-object-in-blender/